# db2 Error SQL1224N and SQLSTATE=55032

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

I am facing following error while connecting to db2 database `"Error SQL1224N and SQLSTATE=55032"` with datastage or dbvisualzer.

While when I am connecting with putty, I am able to connect

```
-sh-4.1$ db2 connect to testdb1 user testuser using test123

   Database Connection Information
 Database server        = DB2/AIX64 9.7.5
 SQL authorization ID   = TESTUSER
 Local database alias   = TESTDB1
```

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error message.

Comment: Check `db2diag.log` for more details on what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

After database restart problem solved.

Comment: I do appreciate the very late answer/reply of the problem you addressed. If you remember something more than just reboot, then update your answer please. Although user Abdul Malik is right, with this action you clear the question from its long outstanding on the "unsovled" question list. (i.m.o. this should have been a reply beneath your question but hey.. after four years no claim for fame... who cares?!).

Comment: You've got my upvote for clearing the question from queue. .. waiting for an update how to really solve this mystery you addressed.